# When i restart computer chrome auto restore setting

Tags: google-chrome

My computer run Window 7. When i restart my computer chrome auto logout and restore settings. How can i setting chrome auto login to chrome account when computer start. I searched on internet but no solution. Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

I quote Google Support:

> Please note that if you sign out of your account, the 'Stay signed in' function will be turned off.
>
> If you're not being automatically signed in even though you haven't
>   signed out, you may need to enable your cookies. Then try signing in
>   again.
>
> If you already have cookies enabled, try clearing your browser's
>   cache. If that doesn't fix the problem, next try clearing the
>   browser's cookies. This may resolve your problem. You'll need to check
>   the 'Stay signed in' box next time you sign in.

Also you will be automatically logged out if you surf in permanent Incognito mode.

Check if you have Administration rights on your chrome.exe. (Right-click, properties)